# ie8 / jquery issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am having an IE8 issue with my jquery code.
As far as I can tell when I change some content in a dom document it works if the change is minor.
So this works:

```
$("#element").html("<p>hi</p>");
```

But the following is not working, where the variable is a more complex dom element like a web form.

```
$("#element").html(variable);
```

How should I be inserting or changing the dom for ie8?
Thanks,

Mat

Comment: It should work, post your variable content.

Comment: Actually your reply was enough as it led me to look more closely at the element I was injecting into the dom and of course it was not formatted properly. Thanks